# how to debug 404 Codeigniter [Merge pull request #3319]

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, routes, http-status-code-404

I set this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome/welcome";
```

As i see DIR :: welcome, Class :: welcome, File :: welcome.php
I take exception 404 - Page not found.

If i pushing back welcome.php to Controllers DIR, and change $route['default_controller'] to 'welcome' = it works. They not work with dirs in /controllers/. On my CI 2.1.4 all works correctly, i try to update CodeIgniter, what i need the Migrations.

//

i did use:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

logfile:

```
ERROR - 2014-11-13 17:13:37 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

So, can someone help?

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: where is your welcome.php located? /application/controllers/welcome/welcome.php? or at /application/controllers/welcome.php?

Comment: shaiful Islam, welcome/welcome.php, as you post in first row. This bug is seen some times with i put default_controller = 'admin', they not requesting class.

Comment: Craig, i simple move welcome.php from controllers DIR, to controllers/welcome DIR, and they have not to find them.

Comment: Just for record, in CI3 sub directory is no more allowed for the 'default_controller'. It must be directly in the 'controllers' directory. [it was allowed in CI2]